# build-helper-maven-plugin add-test-resource error

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, maven-plugin, build-helper-maven-plugin

I have this project structure:

```
/src
    /main
        /java
        /resources
    /test 
        /java
        /resources
    /it
        /java
        /resources
```

`test` for unit tests and `it` for integration tests. I'm using [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) to add additional test sources/resources to the classpath for later use [maven-surfire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) for run
`unit tests` and [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) for `integration tests`.

Plugin config as belows:

```
<plugin>                                                         
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>                          
   <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>      
   <version>1.9.1</version>      
   <executions>                                                  
      <execution>                                                
         <id>add-integration-test-sources</id>                   
         <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>                    
         <goals>                                                 
            <goal>add-test-source</goal>                         
         </goals>                                                
         <configuration>                                         
            <sources>                                            
               <source>src/it/java</source>                      
            </sources>                                           
         </configuration>                                        
      </execution>                                               
      <execution>                                                
         <id>add-integration-test-resources</id>                 
         <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>                  
         <goals>                                                 
            <goal>add-test-resource</goal>                       
         </goals>                                                
         <configuration>                                         
            <resources>                                          
               <directory>/src/it/resources</directory>
            </resources>                                         
         </configuration>                                        
      </execution>                                               
   </executions>                                                 
</plugin>
```

This works fine for the `test-sources` (they are coppied correctly to /target/test-classes) but doesn't copy **test-resources**. I've tried different combinations of `<configuration>`: use `<resource>` instead `<directory>`, use an specific file instead a directory...but neither works.

Stacktrace with the error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginConfigurationException: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.9.1:add-test-resource for parameter directory: Cannot configure instance of org.apache.maven.model.Resource from src/it/resources
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:597)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:529)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:92)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
```

*PROVISIONALLY*, I've fixed it adding the integration tests resources to maven `<build>` configuration:

```
<build>
...
    <testResources>                               
       <testResource>                             
          <directory>src/it/resources</directory> 
       </testResource>                            
    </testResources>    
</build>
```

But I would prefer to have centralized all classpath modifications under `build-helper-maven-plugin`.
Can anyone post example with a correct config?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to the javadoc of the [maven-build-helper-plugin:add-test-resources](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html). The `resources` is an array of `org.apache.maven.model.Resource`. Thus you must configure it this way:

```
<configuration>
    <resources>  
         <resource>                                     
               <directory>/src/it/resources</directory>
         </resource>
    </resources>      
</configuration>
```

Take a look at [how to configure plugin parameters](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Configuring_Parameters).

Comment: sorry I think I must be missing something but the code shown in the answer seems to be same as in the question. I only mention it because I am getting the same error as reported in the question but have the configuration shown in the answer.

Comment: @robbie70 the configuration has a slight difference. In my question the path is `configuration/resources/directory` while in the answer is `configuration/resources/resource/directory`

Comment: ah yes apologies my mistake...thanks for clarifying